# Android Studio not downloading any sdk and tools on Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to download an Android Sdk from Sdk-Tools or from Sdk-Platform in Android-Studio it just give me an error and tells me to read logs. Can someone help me with logs?

Edit: My Android-Studio is installed in /home/abled/android-studio

Log: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/6v4p55n5rZ/

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a problem of access, use this on Ubuntu to gain access
`chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/bin/android-studio`
If not you should probably download the sdk manually

Comment: This helped me and solved my problem. Accepted as answer. Thanks.